# how to join a subquery that returns one result?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need help with a sub query..
Just to simplify the problem

I have a customer table  (only have unique customers)

```
Cust ID, Cust Name
```

I have a sales table (have multiple entries for the customers)

```
SaleID, CustID, DatePurchase, Amount
```

I want to return all the customers but only show their latest Purchase

```
John Smith     02/05/2018
Jane Smith     02/10/2018
```

I want to someone use a join....

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OUTER APPLY (Oracle 12c)`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cust c
OUTER APPLY (SELECT *
             FROM Sales s
             WHERE c.cust_id = s.sales_id
             ORDER BY s.DatePurchase DESC
             FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) sub;
```

---

Alternatively:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT c.*,s.Amount, s.DatePurchase, s.SaleId
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.Cust_id ORDER BY s.DatePurchase DESC) AS rn
  FROM Cust c
  LEFT JOIN Sales s
    ON c.Cust_id = s.Cust_id
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
SELECT CustID, CustName, SaleID, DatePurchase, Amount
FROM
(
    SELECT c.*, s.SaleID, s.DatePurchase, s.Amount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.CustID ORDER BY s.DatePurchase DESC) rn
    FROM customer c
    LEFT JOIN sales s
        ON c.CustID = s.CustID
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Note that those customers who have no sales records at all would have `NULL` reported for the sale ID, purchase date, and amount.  We could replace these with placeholders using `COALESCE`, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Besides other answers, there is also an option to do is using `dense_rank` construct.

So in your case:

```
select c.CustID, max(s.DatePurchase) keep (dense_rank FIRST order by s.DatePurchase desc) 
from customers c
LEFT JOIN sales s on s.CustID = c.CustID
group by c.CustID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple subquery as below

```
SELECT c.Cust_Name,
    s.DatePurchase
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN sales s
INNER JOIN (SELECT Cust_ID, 
            MAX(DatePurchase) dpur 
            FROM sales GROUP BY Cust_ID) s1 ON s1.Cust_ID = s.Cust_ID
    AND s1.dpur = s.DatePurchase
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the latest purchase date, use `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.CustName, MAX(s.DatePurchase)
FROM customer c INNER JOIN
     sales s
     ON c.custid = s.custid
GROUP BY c.custid, c.custname;
```